# Restrict a page in Bolt CMS to a set of users

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm working with Bolt CMS and I would like to create a new section on our website that is only accessible by a set of authenticated users. These users can only view the pages within this section of the site. Anonymous users would not see this section of the website in the menu, nor would they be able to navigate to it.

I see where I can create content types and assign roles to the types via `permissions.yml`, but how does that translate to authenticated page views? Is this possible without custom coding?

Answer (score 0):

Backend permissions do not carry over to the front end, they are very deliberately kept separate.

There is an extension (bolt/members) being developed for the upcoming Bolt v3 that will implement this functionality, but still very separately from the backend.

Comment: So, in other words, there isn't something today in Bolt or in an existing extension that allows me to create a "Members Only" section of my website?